# Why on earth won't my php page work?

Tags: php

Current state of my .php file: http://rich2233.comoj.com/file2.php

I have two issues: First, when the page loads, all my time fields are disabled (See site above). Second, when I hit submit I get the following error: invalid argument supplied for foreach() in on line 8.

Can anyone help me fix this?

```
 My .txt looks like this:
 8:00 am|Rich Jones
 9:00 am|Available
 ......
 5:00 pm|Available
```

Code:

```
  <?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    $find_name = $_POST['name'];
    $find_time = $_POST['time'];
    $filename = getcwd() . "test.txt";
    $lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
foreach($lines as $key => $line)
{
        list($time, $name) = explode('|', $line);
        if($time == $find_time && $name == "Available")
        {
        $lines[$key] = $time."|".$find_name;
        file_put_contents( $filename , $lines );
        break;
     }
     }

  }
// Read the file into an array
$users = file("test.txt");
$hours_taken = array();

// Begin Table
echo "<table align = 'center' border='2' width='50%' cellspacing='0' 
    cellpadding='0'>";
echo "<caption> Sign/Up Sheet </caption>";
echo "<tr><td><b>Time</b></td><td><b>Name</b></td></tr>";

// Cycle through the array
foreach ($users as $user) {

    // Parse the line
    list($time, $name) = explode('|', $user);
array_push($hours_taken, $time);

    // Remove newline 
    $name = trim($name);

    // Output the data in a two column table
    echo "<tr><td>".$time."</td><td>".$name."</td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";

// Assuming same order of rows in users.txt
$hours = array('8:00 am', '9:00 am', '10:00 am','11:00 am', '12:00 pm', '1:00 pm', 
    '2:00 pm', '3:00 pm', '4:00 pm', '5:00 pm'); 

$i = 1;
echo '<form method="post" action="">';
echo 'Name:<input type ="text" id="name" name="name" size="20" maxlength="40" />';
echo '<select name="time"><option selected>-- Select time --</option>';
foreach ($hours as $hour) {
if (in_array($hour, $hours_taken)) {
    echo '<option disabled=disabled>'. $hour .'</option>';
}
else {
    echo '<option value='. $i .'>'. $hour .'</option>';
}
$i++;
}
echo '<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up!" />';
echo '</form>';



  ?>
```

Comment: I don't see a function anywhere in there… `;)`

Comment: For the disabled fields, try using $_GET or $_REQUEST. As for the second issue, echo out each field after it's set and put a few echos in the foreach to see whats happening with the variables.

Comment: foreach() error is because it's not reading in the test.txt file.  Rather than `getcwd()` just use $filename = './test.txt'

Comment: Have you dumped `$hours_taken` to make sure it's populated with information?

Comment: @Biotox Nothing prints when I try to dump the value of $hours_taken...is it possible I messed up when trying to create the variable?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);`

are your friends. assuming you're in a dev environment of course ;)

Comment: Functions return an error value if they fail. You need to check for those instead of blindly assuming everything "went okay".

Comment: @hakre: I put my code in functions.   Returned no error.

Comment: All: the value $hours_taken returns the line "Array", thus I think this is why everything is disabled.  How can I modifying my code to get it running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

Just be sure that test.txt is readable and writable...

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
    $find_name = $_POST['name'];
    $find_time = urldecode($_POST['time']);
    $lines_handle = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    while (($buffer = fgets($lines_handle, 4096)) !== false)
    {
        list($time, $name) = explode('|', $buffer);
        $time = trim($time);
        $name = trim($name);
        if ($time == $find_time && $name == "Available")
        {
            $lines[] = $time."|".$find_name;
        }
        else
        {
            $lines[] = $time."|".$name;
        }
    }
    $lines_handle = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    foreach ($lines as $line)
    {
        fwrite($lines_handle, $line . "\n");    
    }
}
// Read the file into an array
$users_handle = fopen("test.txt", "r");
//$users = file("test.txt");
$hours_taken = array();

// Begin Table
echo "<table align = 'center' border='2' width='50%' cellspacing='0' 
    cellpadding='0'>";
echo "<caption> Sign/Up Sheet </caption>";
echo "<tr><td><b>Time</b></td><td><b>Name</b></td></tr>";

// Cycle through the array
while (($buffer = fgets($users_handle, 4096)) !== false)
{
    // Parse the line
    list($time, $name) = explode('|', $buffer);
    if (trim($name) != "Available")
    {
        array_push($hours_taken, $time);    
    }

    // Remove newline 
    $name = trim($name);

    // Output the data in a two column table
    echo "<tr><td>".$time."</td><td>".$name."</td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";

// Assuming same order of rows in users.txt
$hours = array('8:00 am', '9:00 am', '10:00 am','11:00 am', '12:00 pm', '1:00 pm', 
    '2:00 pm', '3:00 pm', '4:00 pm', '5:00 pm'); 

$i = 1;
echo '<form method="post" action="">';
echo 'Name:<input type ="text" id="name" name="name" size="20" maxlength="40" />';
echo '<select name="time"><option selected>-- Select time --</option>';
foreach ($hours as $hour) {
if (in_array($hour, $hours_taken)) {
    echo '<option disabled=disabled>'. $hour .'</option>';
}
else {
    echo '<option value='. urlencode($hour) .'>'. $hour .'</option>';
}
$i++;
}
echo '<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up!" />';
echo '</form>';



  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

and you are missing a directory separator:

public_htmltest.txt

```
$filename = getcwd() . "test.txt";
```

try this way:

```
$filename = getcwd() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "test.txt";
```

Comment: This seems to get rid of the error and when I press submit, the page refreshes.  The fields are still disabled.  Any ideas on how to fix them?

Comment: can you give me the content of test.txt too

Comment: A sample line in test.txt looks like this: 8:00 am|Rich Jones. I went ahead and added a sample to my question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> : invalid argument supplied for foreach() in on line 8.

This line is causing your error:

```
$lines = file( $filename , FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
```

Your `$lines` variable is null or not an array.